# Highcharts v7.1.2 width scaling issue when using css transform scale

Tags: highcharts, css-transforms

I've just updated from Highcharts V6.1.1 to the latest (V7.1.2) and now I have an issue where charts are not correctly scaled width wise when contained in a css transform scale.

The JSFiddle below shows the problem (apologies for the small images, they're scaled to show the problem).
Using V6.1.1 (uncomment in fiddle) works correctly;

[image: Not Working]

Whereas using latest, V7.1.2, the chart does not fill the container;

[image: Not Working]

https://jsfiddle.net/mattscotty/L4fo02uk/

```
#outerContainer {
    transform: scale(0.315395);
    transform-origin: left top;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue is a Highcharts bug reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10782

As a workaround, set `chart.width` property to the same value as the container width:

```
chart: {
    width: 800
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wtf75o9s/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.width